# HTC wildfire HTC 2.2 device not found

Tags: android

I have HTC wildfire  HTC 2.2. I have connected in PC using usb cable.When I run the application , It didn't show any android device in my computer. Then I tried through command prompt also.I also say like this:

```
  C:\android-sdk-windows>adb shell
  error: device not found
```

Please help me how can I install my apk? I have database also want to setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the debugging mode of your device. Go to `Settings` -> `Applications` -> `Development` and ensure that the check mark on the Debug Mode is present.

Next, you need to have the drivers installed of your HTC Device. Then restart `adb` and reconnect your handset - you will all be done.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ADB drivers installed?

Comment: You mean android-sdk-windows?. When I check through Manage->device->ADB is showing yellow color mark.

Comment: I think it means the driver is not installed. Search the HTC website for the ADB drivers.